# Differences in Regression model for Dummy Coding (factor vs. recode)

Tags: r, regression, categorical-encoding

I have the following problem: I generate Dummy Variables with the *recode* and the *factor* command. In my regression I got different output for the "lower middle" variable and couldn't explain why this was happening.
In the original data set, the variable was coded as follows: lower class = 1; lower middle class = 2; middle class = 3; upper middle class = 4 and upper class = 5.

[image]

```
library(car)

## Dummy Coding Class

data_WPA$LowMidCl <- recode(data_WPA$cot_class, "1=0; 2=1; 3=0; 4=0; 5=0")
data_WPA$MidCl <- recode(data_WPA$cot_class, "1=0; 2=0; 3=1; 4=0; 5=0")
data_WPA$UppMidCl <- recode(data_WPA$cot_class, "1=0; 2=0; 3=0; 4=1; 5=0")
data_WPA$UppCl <- recode(data_WPA$cot_class, "1=0; 2=1; 3=0; 4=0; 5=1")

## Class as Factor

data_WPA$FacClassDummy <- factor(data_WPA$cot_class, labels = c("lower class", "lower middle class", "middle class", "upper middle class", "upper class"))

## LM Model

library(stargazer)

ModelFacClass <- lm(self_physatt ~ LowMidCl + MidCl + UppMidCl + UppCl, data = data_WPA)
ModelClass <- lm(self_physatt ~ FacClassDummy, data = data_WPA)

stargazer(ModelClass, ModelFacClass, title = "Regression", out = "Regression.html")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a mistake in your coding.

```
data_WPA$UppCl <- recode(data_WPA$cot_class, "1=0; 2=1; 3=0; 4=0; 5=1").
```

should be:

```
data_WPA$UppCl <- recode(data_WPA$cot_class, "1=0; 2=0; 3=0; 4=0; 5=1").
```

This means the lower middle class coefficient in your analysis with the recoded variables is the correct value (0.495) minus the upper class coefficient (2.527).  $0.495-2.527 = -2.032$

Comment: Thank you! In the 2 hours I spent trying to find the error, I completely overlooked it.